# Can't understand how recursive functions can work without return statement in Python

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

Hi I am struggling with understanding how recursion works in Python. I am working in Python 3.5 version in particular. I was studying this implementation of Merge sort algorithm in Python:

```
def mergeSort(alist):
    print("Splitting ",alist)
    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
    print("Merging ",alist)

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
mergeSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

I can't understand how this implemention works, because the MergeSort function has no return statement. Moreover the results of the recursive calls to MergeSort at the top of the function body are not assigned to lefthalf and righthalf variables. So I can't understand how the merging part could be set to work with this implementation. When I run this code in my Python of course it works properly. I suppose that I don't understand closures properly in Python, but it would great if someone could point me to right direction. Thanks in advance!

Here is the version which I understand how it works:

```
def mergeSort(alist):
    print("Splitting ",alist)
    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        lefthalf = mergeSort(lefthalf)
        righthalf = mergeSort(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
    print("Merging ",alist)
    return(alist)
```

Comment: please paste the code into the question, dont use external links as they might break in the future and then people that view this question won't be able to see the code

Comment: Without looking at the code, the most likely explanation is that the implementation you're looking at is sorting the list *in-place*, so it changes the list that is passed in and thus has no need to return anything.

Comment: Very sorry guys! I edited my post and pasted the code.

Answer (score 1):

python passes lists by reference, meaning the original list can be modified by a function that was given that list as a parameter, so when you call the function with:

```
mergeSort(lefthalf)
mergeSort(righthalf)
```

`lefthalf` and `righthalf` are themselves sorted, notice how the outside call to `mergeSort()` also assumes the original list is modified, it doesn't return a new sorted list, as i said it **sorts the existing list**

Comment: Ok now I can see that. Like here: 
def myfunc(alist):
    alist.append(2)

def testf(alist):
    myfunc(alist)
    return(alist)

testf([1,2,3]) will return [1,2,3,2]

Answer (score 1):

Can I recommend pasting your code here: http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

And then click on 'Visualize execution'. You will see how your code performs and which the state of each variable is after every line.

Answer (score 0):

Merge sort works in two steps. First, it divides the list in half recursively until it produces lists with one member. In the code you have mentioned, `if len(alist)>1:` recursively Break the list. 
In the second step, it just merges small pieces in the correct order until the first list (but in order) is created. So in the second step, it first combines list with one member, the combine lists with two members, and so. `while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):`, 
`while i < len(lefthalf):` and `while j < len(righthalf):` parts in the code merge the pieces.

Comment: Of course your explanation is right, but I didin't struggle with understanding of the algorithm itself, but rather with the Python implementation, so sorry I won't accept your answer it, because it wasn't my question.